# Mockito unable to mock a class with Optional.of

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class which contains the following line

```
private static final Optional<Integer> DEFAULT_RETRY_COUNT = Optional.of(AppConfig.findInteger("abc"));
```

Mockito is unable to mock this class. It is not able to intialize this class. Please help

Comment: You cannot mock static methods with Mockito sadly, you can use `PowerMockito` for that.

Comment: Is `AppConfig` class your custom class? You can access its `findInteger` method in a non-static way, then you can mock it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue was with static optional of. Can anyone help me with return type of Optional.of while mocking?

Comment: I told you a way already, you shouldn't mock `Optional.of`, never mock anything but your own classes (as much as possible) -> make `AppConfig.findInteger` non-static, is it your own class?

Comment: If ypou find something is hard to test you most likely have a desing problem in your code. In your case it is the refuse of *dependency injection*. Since the value of `DEFAULT_RETRY_COUNT` is obviously determined at runtime (and not at compile time) it should not be a constant, but a (final) member of the class and its value should be passed in via constructor.